# Interpretation of にはな in this sentence

Tags: translation, word-choice, particles, contractions

I know that based on the title it might sound a bit odd, but thing is, there's a video game I like and it only has an English dub and Japanese subtitles.
There's a line (which is spoken by a guy), which at least for a part, I think the final な used in the sentence is an emphatic particle which I hear most in case of guys.
This is how the quote sounds like in English:

> Now, get out of my way or there will be some consequences!

A lot of lines were adapted and don't always have a close meaning, sometimes they differ a lot. Here is the subtitle for this line in Japanese:

> 力ずくでここを通りたいくらいにはな。

He is saying this to someone that wants to interfere with his plan, does the Japanese subtitle retain a similar meaning like the English one? I think it's saying "I'll get through here (or get out of here) by force" (since they do engage in a fight. But the part about 通りたいくらい**にはな** baffles me a bit. I feels like colloqual speech, which I'm not very good at. Can someone tell what kind of nuance is there and how should that phrase sound like better?

 Thank you!

Comment: その前の文も書いてもらえますか。（ところで「～たいくらい」の意味は分かります？）

Comment: @Chocolate
はい、「～たいくらい」のこと分かりますが。ちなみに前の字幕は「よく分かったよ。だが引き下がるつもりはないね。」主人公が相手にこの言葉を言った。